# Can I display emacs buffer modification history?

Tags: emacs, vi

I've used vi for decades, but I'm trying to improve my emacs skills.

In vi, I often check the status of my buffer by issuing this command:

```
:w !diff - %
```

Is there a command in emacs that I can use to remind myself of what changes I have made recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the options listed on the Emacs wiki here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrackChanges

Comment: Thanks. That page suggests `M-x diff-buffer-with-file`, which is exactly what I asked for. Additionally, it lists `M-x highlight-changes-mode`, which may be what I actually want.

Answer (score 1):

[Undo Tree](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree) can do something similar (visualizing buffer versions), butI don't know if it can do diff, though it  would be trivial to implement. You may want to suggest this to the author.